# Lie bracket on the unshifted tangent complex?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, derived-algebraic-geometry

My problem is as follows: if $X$ is a derived scheme, or derived stack, or any kind of a space where tangent complex makes sense, I guess there should be a lie bracket on its tangent complex, extending the notion of commutator of vector fields in smooth underived spaces. However, I am unable to find anything written in this direction.

As a special case, in affine derived schemes (or just cdga's), I can restrict to cofibrant models and consider the module of graded derivations, but in general I would then need to pull back the tangent complex along the (co)fibrant replacement map, and then it is not clear to me if the bracket passes to the quotient.

What I imagine (mostly following answers to a similar question [What is the relation between the Lie bracket on TX as commutator and that coming from the Atiyah class?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143269/what-is-the-relation-between-the-lie-bracket-on-tx-as-commutator-and-that-comi)) is that one can think of the tangent complex as "representing" the formal completion of the diagonal of the product groupoid $X\times X$ and hence have a structure of Lie algebroid. Or alternatively, that there should be (roughly speaking) some kind of a bracket that is Koszul dual to the de Rham differential. But I can't find any of this written down. Maybe it is just that my googling skills failed me. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In the affine case it's straightforward, since the complex of derivations on a cdga is automatically a dgla, and is a model for the tangent complex provided the cdga is cofibrant. Functoriality is then tricky, but the methods in section 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01940 give DGLAs of tangent vectors (and indeed polyvectors) on derived DM stacks. Artin stacks get even trickier, but are dealt with in section 3, involving resolutions by Lie algebroids.

Comment: I agree, but I don't want to restrict to a cofibrant model. Sometimes it is not obvious what should be a nice (small) fibrant model of an affine scheme. I want to start with any cdga, take tangent complex, and have a bracket

Comment: Cofibrant resolutions always exist, and it suffices to take what used to be called quasi-smooth (freely generated as a graded algebra by projective modules over a smooth algebra). How are you taking a tangent complex without cofibrant replacement?

Comment: I didn't know for quasi-smooth, do you have reference for them?

Comment: I mention it somewhere in https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07936 (calling them semi-smooth, though that's also ambiguous). It's easy enough to do by hand, as they have the right cohomology, so you get a zigzag of DGLA quasi-isomorphisms to the tangent complex of a cofibrant replacement.

Comment: Tnx, also, if I take tangent complex via such resolutions, I get it as dg module over the cofibrant model which means that i still have to pull it back to the original space (algebra). But will the bracket descend to the quotient?

Comment: Not in general, as it isn't linear w.r.t. the multiplication. The complex is still quasi-isomorphic without pulling back, anyway.

Comment: Tnx a lot for your help. Just to verify if I understood you right: if I have a cdga A, it is not clear if there exists an A-module, which is a model for a tangent complex, and which has a bracket on it ( or even better a dg lie algebroid structure T_A -> Der(A) ) –

Comment: There is also a definition of the Lie algebra structure on vector fields on laft-def prestacks (prestacks admitting a nice deformation theory) in Gaitsgory--Rozenblyum's book, volume 2, Chapter 8, Section 7.2.